# Delete get variables and .php using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to solve some htaccess question and I'm not able to reach the solution.
I have the following html:

`<a href="www.site.com/home.php?Idi="English">English</a>
<a href="www.site.com/home.php?Idi="Française">Française</a>`

and the goal is that user just gets in its address bar:

`www.site.com/home/English`

or

`www.site.com/home/Française`

Obviously, the get variables should arrive to home.php to be processed.

Also, the site has other pages with extension .php and I got delete each extension with:

`Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]`

Further, I would like the starting page:

`www.site.com/home.php`

would show as:

`www.site.com/home/English`

I have seen a lot of tutorials and posts concerning it, but I am not able to solve it.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks

***EDITED***:

Finally, as UnskilledFreak suggested me, I changed the original links to:

```
<a href="www.site.com/home/English">English</a>
<a href="www.site.com/home/Française">Française</a>
```

and the htaccess is as:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
#Receive site.com/home/Language and internally processes site.com/home.php?Idi=Language
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^home/(English)/?$ home.php?Idi=English [QSA,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^home/(Française)/?$ home.php?Idi=Française [QSA,NC,L]
#Receive site.com/something and internally goes to site.com/something.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```

To avoid the crash of css, js and other links loaded in new pages, I added a `/` before every path of the html.

The htaccess is placed in the root.
The 'home' folder doesn't exist in the server.

Comment: put in your href the url u want the user shown, your .htaccess has to rewrite (.*).php(.*) to $1.php?get=$2, then explode the slashes in $_GET["get"]. now u will have an array with all params given

Comment: May be I should re-ask the question because there are more links adressing to the same .php:<a href="www.site.com/home.php?Idi="Française">Française</a>

Comment: well if im not wrong, my post will do that to, in the exploded array on offset 1 u will find what u want, offset 0 should be "home" and 1 "english" or "francaise" or whatever typed in

Comment: I understood that I should change the link for <a href="www.site.com/home">English</a> .But if the link doesn't include the variable, how the option of the user could arrive to the server?

Comment: well if the link is www.site.com/home/english, and u want to use my solution, then the array holds at offset 0 "home" and on 1 "english" - if the link is www.site.com/home/francaies then 1 is "francaise" - but if www.site.com/home, then offset 1 is not been setted, so check if it isset, if not set offset 1 to eg english by default

Comment: Ok, I have changed the href to ="www.site.com/home/English" and added RewriteRule ^home/([^/.]+)/?$ home\.php?Idi=$1 [L] . The result is the url shows well, the page loads, but without css and images. It seems that can't recognize the paths to the folders.

Comment: i've getting the same error on some pages with that sort of rewrite, my solution was to add a leading slash to the css and js files, eg <link href="path/to.css"> to <link href="/path/to.css">

Comment: op: not yet enough to chat

Comment: As you recommended, I added / before the paths, and it crashes the <a> links published by the new page loaded (they search for i.e. /home/Culture and it should be /Culture ).
So, I changed the links of the new pages from php by adding a / before the path, and now it works!

Thank you at all!
(my apologizes for extending me in these commentaries)

Comment: ur welcome ;) should i add it as an answer so you can close the question?

Comment: Yes, please.. I edited the question with additional information, too.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the comments explain AND the edited Post above, it'll work ;)

but here is another solution i get and works too:

in my document_root i've added a folder called `test`, in there i've got 4 files with following content:

`.htaccess`

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . /test/index.php [L]
```

`index.php` - a wrapper for rewrite and testlinks

```
echo'
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <title>Rewrite Test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/test/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="/test/home/english">English</a><br>
        <a href="/test/home/francaise">Francaise</a><br>
';
$get = explode("/",$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
$get = array_slice($get,2); // ignoring first empty key and folder 'test'

#echo "<pre>".print_r($get,true)."</pre>";

if(file_exists($get[0].".php"))
    require($get[0].".php");
else
    echo 'file '.$get[0].'not found';    

echo'
    </body>
</html>';
```

`home.php` - as requested

```
<?php
echo 'in home.php, you have choosen:'.$get[1];
?>
```

`style.css` - only as test that file access will work

```
body {
    color:#ff8800;
    font-weight:bold:
}
```

tested and works as expected :)

Comment: 1up For the help&orientation to solve the issue and for the explanation
(I still cannot score the answer, I have not enough reputation still, lol)

Comment: no problem, main thing: your problem is solved and ur welcome ;)