# htaccess two variables two landing pages

Tags: php, .htaccess, variables, clean-urls, nice

i have already implemented and working the following:

```
http://domain.com/collections/ford
```

from the following url:

```
http://domain.com/collections.php?brand=ford
```

using the

```
RewriteRule ^collections/$1/(.*)$ collections.php?company=$1 [L]
```

This works perfectly. Now i need to implement a subcategory on those pages. They should look like:

```
http://domain.com/collections/ford/classic
```

from

```
http://domain.com/collections.php?brand=ford&collection=classic
```

but instead of using the same php page as previously (collections.php), i want to use a different one (year.php) and two variables.Both year.php and collections.php reside on the root of my site.

The question is how should i modify my htaccess tp achieve the desired result? Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: Did you just link to localhost?

Comment: look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27315981/delete-get-variables-and-php-using-htaccess/27321869#27321869

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^collections/([^/]+)/?$ collections.php?company=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^collections/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ collections.php?brand=$1&collection=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```